# Mercurial adding new file gives no match found error

Tags: mercurial, version-control

I have a strange problem with updating Mercurial. Everytime when I add a file to my repository and then update another location of the repository (for example with in CI process), the error "no match found" occures. Then when I remove to whole folder and clone it again there are no problems and the new added file(s) are there. Updating and removing doesnt give problems

When I do "a" Verify the following is shown:

> data/test.txt.i@54: missing revlog! 
>   54: empty or missing test.txt 
>   test.txt@54: b80de5d13875 in manifests
>   not found 3 integrity errors
>   encountered! (first damaged changeset
>   appears to be 54)

Any idea what could be causing this?

EDIT

The complete trace:

> ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException:
>   Source control operation failed:
>   abort: data/test.txt.i@b80de5d13875:
>   no match found! . Process command: hg
>   update --noninteractive    at
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.ProcessSourceControl.Execute(ProcessInfo
>   processInfo)    at
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Sourcecontrol.Mercurial.Mercurial.GetSource(IIntegrationResult
>   result)    at
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult
>   result)    at
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest
>   request)

Comment: Can you post a trace showing the exact commands you're running and the output they give?

Comment: It sounds like you somehow managed to get a corrupt repository.  This more properly belongs on the mercurial mailing list or the freenode IRC channel because it looks like a bug.

Comment: It's not running a trace, it's giving a list of the exact commands you run and what their output is.  Basically cut & paste the terminal window in which your having the problem showing the relevant stuff.

Comment: I added the full error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "repository corruption" is not patent here, since you can clone again, and retrieve the all content (old and newly added).
So the different points to check are:

1/ process conflict of some kind (something preventing `data/test.txt.i@b80de5d13875` to be written, even so the file content is recorded)
2/ **[`hg revlog`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Revlog)** and `hg debugindex`, to check out the versions actually recorded in your repo.
3/ **[`hg verify`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RepositoryCorruption?highlight=(hg%5C+verify))** to rule out any repo corruption.
4/ [check the integrity of your repo](http://marc.info/?l=mercurial&m=120594475414715&w=2)

Comment: Thanks I am going to try this, will let you know the result

Comment: The issue is solved, I changed the Commit user on the repository and the project folder and now its solved